problem with move_base footprint
I’m working on the guide and came across this error, I don’t understand what this is connected with and how to fix it
roswtf:
WARNING The following node subscriptions are unconnected:

/rviz:
/map_updates
/move_base:
/move_base/cancel

Found 1 error(s).
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

/move_base->/move_base (/move_base/local_costmap/footprint)
/move_base->/move_base (/move_base/global_costmap/footprint)

all the code is like here: https://amperka.ru/blogs/projects/abot-robot-part-2#ros-navigation
chapter about “стек навигации Ros»

Welcome to Robotics Rich, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer practical, answerable questions, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the Robotics question checklist to edit your question to make it clearer.
